# How to send data to a faces-flow?

Tags: jsf-2.2, faces-flow

My use case: the user choose a questionnaire in a form. When the form is submitted, a faces-flow is started to display the questions of the questionnaire.

To send the questionnaire to the flow, in the bean of the flow I inject the CDI bean of the page which contains the form.

I wonder if there are other ways to send the questionnaire to the flow. If there are several ways, what's the best one?

Comment: FYI, there are really only a few articles on how to deal with Faces Flow, so I created one that hopefully covers the basic questions: http://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters via the form and get them in the initializer method called at the initialization of your flow.

Form (just replace the inputHidden parameter with whatever you're using to select your questionnaire)

```
<h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
    <h:commandLink value="Enter myFlow" action="my-flow"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="parameter" name="parameter" value="8"/>
</h:form>
```

Flow

```
@Produces @FlowDefinition
public Flow defineFlow(@FlowBuilderParameter FlowBuilder flowBuilder) {
String flowId = "my-flow";
    flowBuilder.id("", flowId);
    flowBuilder.initializer("#{myFlowBean.startFlow()}");
    ...
}
```

Backing bean

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("my-flow")
public class MyFlowBean implements Serializable {

    public void startFlow() {
        String parameter = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("parameter");
    //now do sthg with the parameter, such as fetching the questionnaire
    ....
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183945/flow-depending-on-external-parameter/21203256#21203256) for more details

Comment: I am trying to make it work with a flow defined in an XML file but I can't define an initializer by <initializer>: the method is never executed. Did you try it?

Comment: In your other answer you reference at the end of this answer, you use an initializer with a parameter but in the javadoc it is written that the expression to invoke for an initializer, must reference a zero-argument method.

Comment: Sorry I've never tried to define a flow using an XML file.

Comment: Concerning the initializer, you're right about the javadoc. Though it did worked for me under WildFly, you'd better stick with the zero-argument method example ;-)

Comment: I have tried your solution with the definition in a class and it works well. Thanks a lot. I will study why I have this problem with the definition in an XML file.

Comment: Is there a comparable method for returning values from the flow?

Answer (score 0):

**Addition to "thomas.g"s helpful answer:**

I had the same problem, but could not fix it with the hiddenInput approach. Despite the prependId="false" attribute my id and name of the hidden input field got changed by the primefaces p:dataTable element I used. The issue could be fixed with the f:param elemtent inside the h:commandLink element:

```
<h:commandLink value="Enter myFlow" action="my-flow" >
    <f:param name="parameter" value="8"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I hope this might be helpfull to someone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the flow xml file using the initializer tag

```
   <initializer>
       #{myFlowBean.startFlow()}
   </initializer>
```

to call the your initialize method in the flow scoped bean